# CENTRAR SPAN DENTRO DE SECTION

Tags: html, css

Como centro el span dentro del section, eh intentado con varios estilos (flex, align-items, vertical middle) por asi decirlo pero nada me genera el centrado correcto que deseo

```
<section class="test">
     <span class="tag">SOY TEXTO DE PRUEBA</span>
</section>

.test{
     background:green;
     width:500px;
     height:100px;
     display: flex; 
     align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agrega esta propiedad para centrar en el eje principal (que por defecto seria un centrado horizontal) ahorita solo estas centrando en el eje secundario (que por defecto te centraria verticalmente)

```
justify-content: center;
```

```css
.test{
     justify-content: center;
     background:green;
     width:500px;
     height:100px;
     display: flex; 
     align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="test">
     <span class="tag">SOY TEXTO DE PRUEBA</span>
</section>
```